# chrome download attribute not working in plain html?

Tags: html, google-chrome, download

I'm currently building an internal website for my office. I want to include a button that downloads an image on click.

After doing some research, I've learned about the new HTML5 `download` attribute and seemed like a simple solution. However, when clicking on the link in chrome, it behaves like a normal link despite having the download attribute within the `<a>` tag. I checked firefox and it seems to work as intended.

I know there are a few similar topics discussed here on this forum, but the caveat in my specific problem is that the internal site I am building is not actually hosted for security reasons, and is instead a folder placed in a shared drive that my coworkers can access.

Because it is not connected online, I suspect this may be the reason behind it not working, but have yet to find anything online to support my theory. Is there a way to get the `download` attribute to work in an offline, plain HTML site? Are there javascript alternatives I can use to add this functionality?

P.S. I've added some sample code just in case I'm overlooking something. I'm using vue to manage all of the content on the site, plus have some animation styles for the download button that may unknowingly contribute to my issue.

```js
/*
  Used to trigger button animation.
  Possibly a factor in the download attribute not working.
*/

$('.animated-button').click(function() {
  $target1 = $('.animated-button');
  $target1.removeClass('animate');
  setTimeout(function() {
    $target1.addClass('animate');
  }, 100);
});
```

```css
/*
  Used to style button and animation for the button.
  Possibly a factor in the download attribute not working.
*/

.button {
  font-family: 'Montserrat', Helvetica, Arial, Sans-Serif;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  width: 200px;
  background: #036CE2;
  border: 2px solid #036CE2;
  border-radius: 5px;
  color: #FFF;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
  position: relative;
  outline: none;
}

.button:active {
  transform: scale(0.9);
}

.button:hover,
.button:focus {
  background: #004CA3;
  border-color: #004CA3;
  color: #fff;
}

.animated-button span {
  display: block;
  padding: 10px 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  color: white;
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}

.animated-button.animate {
  -webkit-animation: success 2s ease;
  -moz-animation: success 2s ease;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
  -moz-animation-iteration-count: 1;
}

.animated-button.animate span {
  -webkit-animation: success-text 1.5s ease;
  -moz-animation: success-text 1.5s ease;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
  -moz-animation-iteration-count: 1;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0.2s;
  -moz-animation-delay: 0.2s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes success {
    0% {}
   15% { background: #62E03C; color: #62E03C; border-color: #62E03C; }
   85% { background: #62E03C; color: #62E03C; border-color: #62E03C; }
  100% {}
}

@-moz-keyframes success {
    0% {}
   15% { background: #62E03C; color: #62E03C; border-color: #62E03C; }
   85% { background: #62E03C; color: #62E03C; border-color: #62E03C; }
  100% {}
}

@-webkit-keyframes success-text {
    0% { opacity:0; transform: translateY(20px)}
   15% { opacity:1; transform: translateY(0)}
   85% { opacity:1; transform: translateY(0)}
  100% { opacity:0; transform: translateY(-20px)}
}

@-moz-keyframes success-text {
    0% { opacity:0; transform: translateY(20px)}
   15% { opacity:1; transform: translateY(0)}
   85% { opacity:1; transform: translateY(0)}
  100% { opacity:0; transform: translateY(-20px)}
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a :href="BDY0100Block.imageUrl" class="button colored full mb-5 animated-button" download>Download Img <span>Downloaded!</span></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="/exact/path/to/your/file/to/be/download" class="button colored full mb-5 animated-button" download>Download Img <span>Downloaded!</span></a>
```

**try out this thing with exact path to your file to be downloaded**